# Opening a Sublime project from the command line without opening a blank window

Tags: bash, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am trying to figure out how to open a Sublime Text project from the command line.

If I type `subl foo.project` for a project that is not open, it opens the project. But if I do this for a project that is already open, it opens a blank window for some reason. I have no idea whether this is a bug or intended behavior.

Is it possible to come up with a command or shell script that takes a project filename, and opens it if it is not open, but focuses it if it is open? If so, how can I do this?

I am using Sublime Text 2.0.1 and OS X 10.8.4. I have `subl` symlinked to `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`.

I found [this post on UserEcho](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/131758-trying-to-open-an-already-opened-project-opens-a-new-empty-window/) and [this post on the forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4882) but there haven't been any meaningful responses. Other than that, I haven't found anything else about this bug.

**EDIT:** I updated to the Sublime Text 3 beta and I still experience this bug. I haven't found a fix or workaround.

Comment: This is strange behavior, maybe a bug? I am on Linux and when I do that for an open project it just focuses.

Comment: Do you by chance have MacPorts installed?

Comment: I don't think I have MacPorts. I am using a recent Mac (not more than a few months old) and I don't remember ever installing it.

Comment: Sublime Text's developer rarely frequents UserEcho. You're more likely to get a response on the official forum http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/

Answer (score 6):

This is a [known](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/131758-trying-to-open-an-already-opened-project-opens-a-new-empty-window/) bug in Sublime Text 2/3 on OSX. The Developers have not made many comments about it, so it might not be something they're working on in the near future.

As for the bash script, you might want to head over to '[Ask Ubuntu'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95904/how-do-i-open-a-file-from-inside-a-bash-script). Lot's of Unix gurus over there who might have a quick fix for you.

Comment: Why would I head to "Ask Ubuntu" for a problem on OS X?

Comment: Because they deal with a lot of Bash scripts. OSX is Unix based.

Comment: If I want to ask a question about something Unix-based, would it be better to ask on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes, you could do that too. I only mentioned that link because it involved a bash script that did exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I tried the `xdg-open` command and it didn't work. Since this is supposedly a known bug, I may wait and see if they fix it.

Comment: @JcKelley did you confirm this on ST3?

Comment: HI, i think this bug could be because of space in user's name. `c:\user\name 1\` results in error that says path `c:\users\name 1\.....\projFolder\1\....\projFolder\` couldn't be found. it just took part after 1 and duplicated it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this combination to switch between projects

```
alias sp='subl --command "close_project"; subl --project'
sp myproject.sublime-project
```

Sometimes though the empty window still appears, then I think you may need a delay

```
alias sp='subl --command "close_project"; sleep 0.2; subl --project'
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a [bug](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/62343-subl-with-no-window-open-doesnt-open-the-file/), still present in my build 3059. A workaround is to wait until the Sublime window is open, and then open the file.

Eg. put the following in your `.bash_profile`:

```
alias edit='subl && sleep 0.1 && subl'
```

(And don't forget to run `source .bash_profile` to refresh.)  On my computer 0.1 seconds was quick enough, but it can be that this value has to be bigger on slower computers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my Mac at the moment to test it, but try playing with the `"open_files_in_new_window"` and/or `"create_window_at_startup"` settings in your `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file. If this behavior isn't a bug on OSX, one or both of those settings should fix it.

Comment: I tried all combinations of those settings set to true, set to false, and not set, and it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue where the `subl` command would **only** open blank windows, very annoying. I posted a fix on the Github issue [here](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/27).

---

Here it is:

If anyone experiences this issue and can't get the `subl` command to stop opening blank windows I solved it with the following steps:

1. Copy your "User Settings" into a file (you'll need to paste them in later)
2. Locate your data folder as described [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html)
3. Move that data folder to a place you can still access it but not in the default location
4. Quit Sublime Text
5. Open Sublime Text
6. (At this point your `subl` command should work, you just need to restore your settings/packages etc...)
7. You should see that Sublime Text now created a new folder where the old one was
8. Replace the `Installed Packages`, `Local` and `Packages` folders in the *new* folder with those of the *old* one
9. Paste your "User Settings" back into the JSON file for your user settings
10. Quit Sublime Text and restart and you should now have your old settings back

I hope this helps